# Is the sequence $\{\Omega(n)\alpha\}$ uniformly distributed in $[0,1)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

For a positive integer $n$, let [$\Omega(n)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#.CE.A9.28n.29.2C_.CF.89.28n.29.2C_.CE.BDp.28n.29_.E2.80.93_prime_power_decomposition) be the number of primes dividing $n$, counted with multiplicities (eg $\Omega(5)=1$, $\Omega(8)=\Omega(12)=3$).

For a real number $x$, let $\{x\}\in[0,1)$ be the fractional part of $x$, so that $x-\{x\}$ is an integer.

**If $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ is an irrational number, is the sequence $\big(\{\Omega(n)\alpha\}\big)_{n=1}^\infty$ [uniformly distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence) in $[0,1)$?**

A sequence $(a_n)$ taking values in $[0,1)$ is uniformly distributed if for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ we have $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1N\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{\displaystyle2\pi ika_n}=0$$

Comment: If the Erd&ouml;s-Kac theorem existed in a more refined version, saying that if you look at the distribution of $\Omega(n)$ over a range of $n$'s, then $\Omega(n)−\log\log n$ is close in total variation distance to a normal random variable, then the answer would be yes.

Comment: The answer is yes. Look up the chapter on the Selberg-Delange method in Tenenbaum's book "Intro to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory".